# How can I keep UIActionSheet from being dismissed when background touched?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactionsheet

The default behavior for the UIActionSheet used to be that touching the background [did *not* dismiss it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7402548/1431728), and in fact did nothing. But with iOS 7 touching the background is equivalent to pressing the `cancelButton`.

I'm modifying some software that needs to be kept to the iOS 6 behavior. How can I keep touches of the background from dismissing the action sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by not using a cancel button.

Check this SO post:

[UIActionSheet in iOS7 dismissing when user taps ANYWHERE on the screen on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775585/uiactionsheet-in-ios7-dismissing-when-user-taps-anywhere-on-the-screen-on-iphone/18902220#18902220)

Comment: Ah, so you mean, setting `cancelButton: nil`, which still allows me to set the text for one of the custom buttons to `@"Cancel"`? Great solution. Thanks for the informative link too.